# Unable to perform action "Promote" on com.mydomain.demoapp because is it not currently supported

Tags: ios, swift, webview, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution

I'm new to iOS developing and swift. I have a simple Single View App that contains a webview and loads my website into that. When i test application on simulator everything works fine.

But when in want to install using distribute in-house apps from a web server with steps explained [here](https://help.apple.com/deployment/ios/#/apda0e3426d7), application downloaded and installed successfully but when i touch on the application icon to run it i get this error in logs:

> Unable to perform action "Promote" on com.mydomain.demoapp because is
>   it not currently supported
>
> All action attempts failed for placeholder: com.mydomain.demoapp

I don't know where to should check and how fix problem.